# Rename [kronos-wfc] to [kronos-workforce-central]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I would like to propose renaming [kronos-wfc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kronos-wfc) to [kronos-workforce-central](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kronos-workforce-central).

Kronos Workforce Central is a set of employee management software for businesses. The tag is primarily  used for questions about the [Workforce Central XML API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9812136/3357935), which can be used to import or manipulate employee data though XML POST requests

It's a fairly small tag, but it seems a bit silly to use an abbreviation when the [official product title](https://www.kronos.com/products/workforce-central-suite) is much more descriptive.

Comment: How does the vendor commonly refer to it? Do they call it "WFC", or do they call it "Workforce Central"? That's what the master tag should match. The other can be created as a synonym, to catch both ways that users might enter it.

Comment: @CodyGray They refer to it as the [Kronos Workforce Central Suite](https://www.kronos.com/products/workforce-central-suite). Google search results show the abbreviation is used [very sparingly](https://www.google.com/search?q=kronos+wfc).

Comment: By the way, [*thank you* for editing that tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16545373)! I've already approved it, but I'll link it here just to make good and sure it gets through. :-) Although, the tag wiki proper needs a bit of love, too. That copy-paste marketing gibberish should have never gotten through in the first place, and a *good* tag wiki should explain what this has to do with programming (i.e., it should be *contextual* to a programming Q&A site). If you have a chance and are knowledgeable, you might consider trying to bang together something.

Comment: Is there, like, an API that we could mention on the wiki? It's still a bit unclear to me what exactly makes this programming-related. And I didn't notice at first, but there appear to be only 3 questions using this tag, so it isn't exactly high-traffic.

Comment: @CodyGray Stored employee data can be loaded or modified using Kronos's XML-based API. Unfortunately, most of the API documentation is not publicly accessible.